# Pandas data frame new column from where logic (receiving keyword error)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want column 'x' to be the same as column 'b' when column 'a' = 'b' but if 'a' does not equal 'b' then I want it 'x' to be (('a'+'b')/2):

```
filename = 'test.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(filename)

df['x'] = np.where(df['a'] = df['b'], df['x'] = df['b']
df['x'] = np.where(df['a'] != df['b'], (df['a'] + df['b']/2))

print(df.head(5))
```

I'm getting error (KeyWord can't be an expression)

Comment: Add df.head() and df.info to this question after the read_csv

Comment: there's a mistake on the first `np.where`, change `df['a'] = df['b']` to `df['a'] == df['b']`, overall please review the correct syntax for `np.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own function and then just use the apply function to have it create your new row.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')

def funct(row):
    if row['a'] == row['b']:
        return row['b']
    else:
        return (row['a'] + row['b'])/2

df['x'] = df.apply(funct, axis=1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   a  b    x
0  1  1  1.0
1  2  2  2.0
2  3  4  3.5
3  4  3  3.5
4  5  5  5.0
5  6  7  6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
df['x'] = np.where(df['a'] == df['b'], df['b'], (df['a'] + df['b'])/2)
```

If `a == b` (note double equals), then `x` column takes the value of `b`, else it takes the value `(a + b)/2`